# high cpu load during rendering

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am rendering rather heavy object consisting of about 500k triangles. I use opengl display list and in render method just call glCallList. I thought that once graphic primitives is compiled into display list cpu work is done and it just tells gpu to draw. But now one cpu core is loaded up to 100%.

Could you give me some clues why does it happen?

UPDATE: I have checked how long does it take to run glCallList, it's fast, it takes about 30 milliseconds to run it

Comment: Do you use a simple game loop or a vsync? Usually, a game loop without a `sleep` takes 100% CPU.

Comment: 30 ms is huge. 30 fps means 33 ms/frame, so you have only 3 ms left... Avoid display lists, btw.

Comment: @Scan, I use FPSAnimator

Comment: @Calvin1602 what is wrong with display lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are hitting the limits on the list length, which are at 64k verteces per list. Try to split your 500k triangles (1500k verteces?) into smaller chunks and see what you get.

btw which graphical chips are you using? If the verteces are processed on CPU, that also might be a problem

Comment: I checked which functions was consuming cpu, they were from atioglx2.dll. Unfortunately I can't check if limit is hit now, some time later. I am using ATI Mobility Radeon HD 2600 graphics card

Comment: @misha Are you sure you didn't get SW rendering? If not, then you broke the limits

Comment: I didn't set any option to do software rendering. That limit 64k is it for one display list or for all, e.g. only one display list can't exceed it, or sum of all display lists can't exceed it?

Comment: @misha That limit is for one list. What I meant, if you use something that is not supported by your HW, you'll get software rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a myth that display lists magically offload everything to the GPU.  If that was really the case, texture objects and vertex buffers wouldn't have needed to be added to OpenGL.  All the display list really is, is a convenient way of replaying a sequence of OpenGL calls and hopefully saving some of the function call/data conversion overhead (see [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm)).  None of the PC HW implementations I've used seem to have done anything more than that so far as I can tell; maybe it was different back in the days of SGI workstations, but these days buffer objects are the way to go.  (And modern OpenGL books like [OpenGL Distilled](http://www.scribd.com/doc/26822695/eBook-Opengl-Distilled) give glBegin/glEnd etc the briefest of mentions only before getting stuck into the new stuff).

The one place I have seen display lists make a huge difference is the GLX/X11 case where your app is running remotely to your display (X11 "server"); in that case using a display list really does push all the display-list state to the display side just once, whereas a non-display-list immediate-mode app needs to send a bunch of stuff again each frame using lots more bandwidth.

However, display lists aside, you should be aware of some issues around vsync and busy waiting (or the illusion of it)... see [this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829881/avoid-waiting-on-swapbuffers)